# Fortran to pass C struct between two C functions

Tags: c, fortran, interop, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a Fortran application that is required to call two C routines.
One to load a file and one to run a calculation on the file about 200 times.
I understand that a C DLL cannot 'save' the loaded struct in a static variable to be reused in the calculate function so I am looking to parse back a void* to Fortran and send it to C calculate function.

The C functions:

```
 __declspec(dllexport) void loadfile(void * file); // Empty pointer should be filled with struct of loaded file

 __declspec(dllexport) void calculate(void * file, double * result); //filled void ptr is used (casted back to my struct first)
```

My Fortran code:

> ```
> module globalFileHolder
>   USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
>   type(C_PTR), save :: fileModule = C_NULL_PTR    
> end module
> ```

Load file routine:

```
SUBROUTINE loadcfile()
  USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
  use globalFileHolder
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTERFACE
       SUBROUTINE loadfile(fm) BIND(C)
       USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
          TYPE(C_PTR)   :: fm
       END SUBROUTINE loadfile
  END INTERFACE 

  TYPE(C_PTR) :: fms = c_null_ptr       
  call loadfile(fms)
  fileModule = fms
  return
  end
```

And finally my routine that is supposed to use the loaded file in a calculation:

> ```
> SUBROUTINE calculatec()
>  USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING 
>   use globalFileHolder
>   IMPLICIT NONE
>   INTERFACE
>        SUBROUTINE calculate(fm,res) BIND(C)
>       USE, INTRINSIC::ISO_C_BINDING
>       TYPE(C_PTR)    , VALUE :: fm  
>       REAL(C_DOUBLE) , value :: res
>   END SUBROUTINE calculate
>   END INTERFACE 
>   TYPE(C_PTR) :: fms 
>   REAL(C_DOUBLE) result
>   fms = C_LOC(fileModule)
>   call calculate(fms,result)
>   return
>   end
> ```

Now the problem I currently have is that the module variable filemodule seems to be filled but when sending it to the calculate function the variable is null after casting it like:

```
myStruct * ms = (myStruct*)file;
```

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Is `res` meant to be an output from `calculate`?  It has the `value` attribute, but the actual argument `result` hasn't had its value defined before the call.

Comment: @francescalus That is indeed true, i have changed it. But the problem resides in the fact that res can never be calculated without having access to the loaded file from the load file function. I never calculate res before i check if fms (the filemodule) has been sent over to the C calculate function properly (as in: its always null unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the `fm` dummy argument in the interface for loadfile is missing the VALUE attribute.

Comment: Hi thanks for your contribution, adding the VALUE attribute has indeed fixed a part. The file now indeed returns properly to the function but the calculate function still receives NULL as data.
*edit: Might it be that storing it in a module between routines is the problem?

Comment: As supplied (and as per francescalus' comment under the question), there is no way that the `loadfile` C function can return information back to the Fortran side of things.  The value of `fms` will always remain C_NULL_PTR across the call to loadfile.  Are you sure your C prototypes are correct?

Comment: You also have an extra VALUE attribute on the res argument of calculate.